# Using replace() in tkinter for changing text input from space to -

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, str-replace

```
Text1 = Text(root,height=1,width=15,background='grey')
Text1.pack()
Text1.replace(" ","-")
```

So this is what i tried to do. I need to make all spaces typed in from the user to "-". So instead of "how are you" it should be "how-are-you". I've tried som different ways. i even tried `Text1=Text1.replace(" ","-")`.

Anyone who could help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the current text using `Text1.get`, replace the contents and update it aagain using `Text`.replace`

```
Text1.replace("1.0", tkinter.END, Text1.get("1.0", tkinter.END).replace(' ', '-'))
```

Comment: I will try this one aswell. Can you explain why it is tkinter.END?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def replace_space():
    var = Text1.get('1.0','end')
    var = str.replace(var, ' ', '-')
    label['text'] = var

root = Tk()

Text1 = Text(root,height=1,width=15,background='grey')
Text1.pack()

button = Button(root, text = 'Go', command = replace_space)
button.pack()

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Tkinter output:

[str.replace()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wusZx.png)

Comment: Yes that’s it. Perfect. Thank you . Didn’t know i had to define it first